# Activity onDestroy confusion

Tags: android

What I understood so far is that `onDestroy` and `onStop`(after Honeycomb) will not get called always if `Activity` is in background and system need to kill the process for memory.

And `onDestroy` and `onStop` will always get called if `Activity` is normally finishing.

Lets say for example, I add a listener to a static field inside `onCreate` and remove the listener inside `onDestroy`. Now 2 things can happen.

- If app get destroyed by system and system terminate its process. So
  all the listeners in that static field will be gone.
- If app normally finishes, then it
  will remove own listener from `onDestroy`

Right ? I know android kills process only but is there some condition that android only kills Activity(without calling `onDestroy`) not the Process ?

Comment: Honeycomb, oops fixed

Comment: Add in onResume(), remove in onPause()

Answer (score 0):

When you call `finish()`, the activity is destroyed, not the whole process

Answer (score 0):

in the android Activities [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) in the lifecycle part , look at the table 1 , it has A summary of the activity lifecycle's callback methods.

there is a column called killable after ? and in the onDestroy method , the killable after is yes .

the column labeled "Killable after?" indicates whether or not the system can kill the process hosting the activity at any time after the method returns, **without executing another line of the activity's code.**

that means The code that you are using in your onDestroy method is not needed at all if the android kill the process .

If destroy is called your acitivity will be removed from the stack and is free for garbage collection anyway with all the resources in it that are only referenced by the activity.

onDestroy() is called only when system is low on resources(memory, cpu time and so on) and makes a decision to kill your activity/application or when somebody calls finish() on your activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is another method to finish your process. In manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".Name" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there some condition that android only kills Activity(without calling onDestroy) not the Process ?

According to android official site,

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

There is no official doc about saying that activity can be killed without calling onDestroy but process will be alive. Regarding to android, only in extreme situations onDestroy won't be called which is process also will be killed.

[refer to here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)